It is posible detect when recaptcha v2 image challange showed?
I have this file to show rectapcha v2 and I need to detect that recaptcha show image challange. This html is displayed in flutter application and I need that capture to enlarge the webview where the recaptcha is displayed

    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    <script>
    
        function onLoad() {

          grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
            'sitekey': '<KEY>', 
            'callback': onSuccess,        
            'expired-callback': onExpired, 
            'error-callback': onError      
          });
        }
  
    function onSuccess(token) {
        alert('Verification successful!');
            if (window.Captcha) {
                window.Captcha.postMessage('success');
            }
       
    }

    function onExpired() {
        console.log("reCAPTCHA expired");
        if (window.Captcha) {
          window.Captcha.postMessage("expired");
        }
    }

    function onError() {
        console.log("reCAPTCHA error or challenge");
        if (window.Captcha) {
          window.Captcha.postMessage("error");
        }
    }

    function onChallangeOpen() {
        if (window.Captcha) {
          window.Captcha.postMessage("challenge");
        }
    }
    </script>

